# using regex anchoring in LFTP

Tags: regex, lftp

I am using the following regex

```
^([[:digit:]]+|\-|\_)+.*.xlsx
```

to match e.g. the filename

```
2020_04_Kontoauszug_67633600.xlsx
```

for a mirror command in LFTP (with option `-i`).

However, this is not working with the anchoring `^` at beginning in LFTP. In a regex tester (https://regex101.com) it works fine. I need the anchor to avoid false matches.

Comment: Your file name can also start with _ or - ?

Comment: no, but does not harm anything, because no files start with _ or -